# Marker issue in catplot seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, markers

I'm trying to execute a command as:

```
temp = sns.catplot(x="Time", y="Total", 
                   hue="Location", data=combo, aspect = 3, 
                   markers = ["x","o","v","s","P","+","D","1","*"])
```

There are 9 locations and hence, I've put 9 markers. I still get

```
  File "C:\Users\dbhadra\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 912, in _update_property
    raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)

AttributeError: Unknown property markers
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you look at the documentation of catplot, https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot you will see there is no property "markers"

Comment: It seems to exist in scatterplot. Any workaround?

Comment: you use sns.scatterplot! https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot

Comment: Look at this example from the seaborn site. 

sns.catplot(x="class", y="survived", hue="sex",
            palette={"male": "g", "female": "m"},
            markers=["^", "o"], linestyles=["-", "--"],
            kind="point", data=titanic);

Comment: That is because of the "kind = "point"", which then allows pointplot() args.

Comment: Two things:
1. scatterplot has no option for aspect ratio?
2. When I execute

: filled_markers = ('o', 'v', '^', '8', 's', 'p', '*', 'h', 'H')
 temp = sns.scatterplot(x="Time", y="Total", 
                   hue="Location", data=combo, markers=filled_markers)

It still gives a plot with only circle markers.

Comment: you need to add, style = 'Location' as an argument. For aspect ratio you can use matplotlib figsize: ```fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10));
ax = sns.scatterplot(ect ect ect)```